# How to Read Multiple .txt Files in a Loop in Python and get count of matching words

Tags: python

I have 2 text files and 2 lists (FIRST_LIST,SECOND_LIST), I want to find out count of each file matching words from FIRST_LIST,SECOND_LIST individually.

```
FIRST_LIST = "accessorizes","accessorizing","accessorized","accessorize"
SECOND_LIST="accessorize","accessorized","accessorizes","accessorizing"
```

(this is not a string I am getting this data ".txt " file format)

text_File1 (contains):

```
This is a very good question, and you have received good answers 
 which describe interesting topics accessorized accessorize.
```

text_File2 (contains):

```
is more applied,using accessorize accessorized,accessorizes,accessorizing
```

output format:

```
File1 first list count=2
File1 second list count=0

File2 first list count=0
File2 second list count=4
```

This code below I have tried to archieve this functionality but not able to get the expected output.
if any help appreciated

Reading all (x.txt Files)

```
import os 
import glob
files=[]

for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    files.append(filename)
```

creating a def function to remove Punctuations

```
# remove Punctuations
import re

def remove_punctuation(line):
return re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', line)
```

Reading Multiple Files fro "filename" in a Loop but it is merging. I need separate each text1 file counts and text2 file counts

```
two_files=[]
for filename in files:
    for line in open(filename):
        #two_files.append(remove_punctuation(line))
        print(remove_punctuation(line),end='')
        two_files.append(remove_punctuation(line))


FIRST_LIST = "accessorizes","accessorizing","accessorized","accessorize"
SECOND_LIST="accessorize","accessorized","accessorizes","accessorizing"


c=[]
for match in FIRST_LIST:
    if any(match in value for value in two_files):
        #c=match+1
        print (match)
        c.append(match)
print(c)
len(c)
d=[]
for match in SECOND_LIST:
    if any(match in value for value in two_files):
        #c=match+1
        print (match)
        d.append(match)
print(d)
len(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you wanted, but I think it's because you are appending the lines from both files in the same list. You should create a list for each. Try:

```
import glob
files=[]

for filename in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    files.append(filename)

# remove Punctuations
import re

def remove_punctuation(line):
    return re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', line)


two_files=[]
for filename in files:
    temp = []
    for line in open(filename):
        temp.append(remove_punctuation(line))
    two_files.append(temp)

FIRST_LIST = "accessorizes","accessorizing","accessorized","accessorize"
SECOND_LIST="accessorize","accessorized","accessorizes","accessorizing"


c=[]
d=[]

for file in two_files:
    temp = []
    for match in FIRST_LIST:
        for value in file:
            if match in value:
                temp.append(match)
    c.append(temp)

    temp2 = []
    for match in SECOND_LIST:
        for value in file:
            if match in value:
                temp2.append(match)
    d.append(temp2)

print('File1 first list count = ' + str(len(c[0])))
print('File1 second list count = ' + str(len(d[0])))

print('File2 first list count = ' + str(len(c[1])))
print('File2 second list count = ' + str(len(d[1])))
```

Comment: It stores TextFile_1 but it is not looping Textfile_2 I need dynamically

Comment: One question to make sure I understand what you trully want. Since LIST1 and LIST2 are the same but the words are in different order, shouldn't the match count for text_File1 be 2 for both lists and not 2 for LIST1 and 0 for LIST2?

Comment: FIRST_LIST  is UK English and SECOND_LIST  is USA English

Comment: They’re written the exact same way. I added the rest of the code according to my previous answer and the rest of your code and it works, but the count number for FIRST_LIST is the same as for the SECOND_LIST because of that. Either way I hope I have helped you.